# How to update password for a existing user with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I'm creating a feature for my website to enable users to reset there password if they forget it.

**packages i'm using...**
Express Js (framework)
passport-local--mongoose,
passport-local,
passport,

i'm using passport method .setPassword in user model but password is not changing

```
router.post('/login/:userID/reset_password',(req, res)=>{
   const NewPass=req.body.password,
         confirm_password=req.body.confirm_password;
         console.log(NewPass);
         if(NewPass==confirm_password){
             console.log(NewPass);
             User.findById(req.params.userID, (err, user)=>{
                 if(err) console.log(err);
                 else
                   {
                       user.setPassword(NewPass,(err, user)=>{
                        if(err) console.log('set pass error'+err);
                        else{
                            console.log('new pass set successfully!!');
                            res.redirect('/login');
                        }

                       });
                   } 
             });

         }
});
```

Comment: You haven't told us the response you are receiving.

Comment: This route is the redirect route after veryfing OTP for resetting password and i'm sending a get request after veryfing OTP,

Comment: I just wanna know how to update password in mongodb using mongoose

Answer (score 0):

I got it...
I just have to write user.save(); after updating passport